# Redirect Unique URL to Different URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

so I have been fiddling around with an idea and I cant seem to get it working.

I have a game where people share my website, each share gets their unique code -

`mydomain.com/?1234567`

What I want to achive is that if a person directly visits my website

`mydomain.com` he/she will stay on that page, but if the user comes from a unique 7 number code then he/she would be sent to `anotherdomain.com`

I tried using .htaccess but was only able to not redirect unique url, while redirecting main domain, exactly the opposite what I wanted.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com/?$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

How to resolve this matter?

Comment: You need to match against querystrings in your rule for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]{7}$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The regular expression above - **^[0-9]{7}+$** will match any numbers with maximum length 7 in query string ,if it matches then The url will redirect to a new location.

Comment: Tried using this, but all traffic remains on main page.

mydomain.com stays where it is supposed to, but `mydomain.com/?1234567` doesn't redirect

Comment: Clear your browser cache or try a diffrent browser.

Comment: Note that the rule will not work with www. in hostname.

Comment: thank you, this works perfect! Only thing I did change is that, since the code is random, it also had letters in it, i didn't mention it before, so no way you could have know that, but if you have letters (Capital and lower-case ones) use this

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-z,A-Z,0-9]{7}$`

Comment: You need this pattern **^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$** it matchs an alphanumbric string with maximum length 7 char, eg : **foo123B** , **123BaR** etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$array = explode('/', $url);
$var = $array[1];

if(strlen($var) == 7){
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: http://anotherdomain.com");
  exit;
}
```